# training DataSet для сегментации одежды

Tags: python, tensorflow

Ребята!
Подскажите ресурсы где есть тренировочный датасет с одеждой, для задачи сегментации.
Или мб у вас имеется?

Или вот у меня имеется набор фото(с обычными картинками и масками которые должны получится на выходе)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
 как с ними работать в сети?

Answer (score 0):

http://yandex.ru/clck/jsredir?bu=a2qn36&from=yandex.ru%3Bsearch%2F%3Bweb%3B%3B&text=&etext=2202.XlVM6IiXw_1G0Dj8jllZf-toOR8ZnhNCAFxr6eP_a9VdInxMSAkF3GMLBoCOORiEFJnwNJbmv4E5xqC5nXkexMZEy6U-kQedhMYfcueSq7Rsb3NyZ3B5dmVtcnJvZnRt.13ef110d6d6836d42f23d162c9b41261f0f7102d&uuid=&state=jLT9ScZ_wbo,&&cst=AiuY0DBWFJ4EhnbxqmjDhbfHH-VoPyBMS-MWlh08XXpPFkcg9wAe7ofrxybB3-vdjDGhIoJbjy164c6poxTvjkhxFNxlfJormeHhhlruFBUhSaQcdBxi1u_874L2UvUx2EfN4NrFMtY3-FHEIr7Myz0D0ut2Yp-aLu0URfrC9MayH0B5S9Q1hEB7mZbG0vN60EMmtMdhz5j43k0WA6z9Z2cAFPWzK4U-grAFCu2dMs931UsmIVKIOuKu8bWB2XWixzDzrejufbGW0-7B_TULMFXepgBukYAcZk5KqsZhTH_jvMc5CzaUQqfa1SvIu_8lcu0uRQEm6Q6O8lkg7RwanWw41VeiSYAu_SS6hNANwWWHF6TVaNh_cTaW_EbzlCnyBix2imi4-wQ68L2e5jBpVjHabhUDmj_sfgBUOw8C7Sbt-lLfMRaqIUGSBIAiu6K3vS-AEIlSnmMAhCXJdJdE1M_O7Cy8Dy735waMu_--7mDnA-4Xq0pBgnVbOHi4M3OLkrq8BiQgUGv9KAFYyHIt5XAthQcvhjHL0YSZGDmF2Fy20XkQ3KKXIPwKRr9O8dbsA0wElNdTIgLnb_YlzglDSxLWFWlVE7I8QNaYPqmGB4TW4qaCzgF5Po4msolXlZ8FQ4SzWx9KtTx4GPuaFq9OVCCCk_JjQrQj8fTTXiFJPts7GUvgfGEFlNdc6uERF98O7ju1s5vFOjSRdsn7XWCCABQvGCZd3F_UGCwyKINzqD_abvk-tpZh9xEw6qAr0-DqFS9K27rN7jVRVxfidYqi1-BOoN1ObVaFJbTPILT4mH8hia-gtQp-IORRiCvHrNobr8-dKZGjcYF1EbrZx6Mnkt4CbfLga6Q8uMbf1k6ejbPmELm8neGa4rZssUJpRzft4azaAhe2imsHmy8tkFnQUfLoo7D6AiILyiKn2Rx3MzCa5Wk3_jlPMn8rwadx8Bhqt6Wt_tEb5Oo6majBVpZtIOycGhRMFUgzj3zsM6aPLC2-66xVc66SR377CPcUQNtCXSaWJWKp7lk,&data=UlNrNmk5WktYejY4cHFySjRXSWhXR0RMeGtWVHpUTWhCMWtUU2VfaFlycHprYnhXbks5UkFBRnNjRVNubVotZXJxNTRjek8tOU9fZ3ZTOWZla19wYnFyd1ZlN0c0QnFBRU5mUWNCLUdsTnV5ZGI1TGVxZUJMdyws&sign=70f14d84cd6f9124ab7a1c2d5c77c124&keyno=0&b64e=2&ref=orjY4mGPRjk5boDnW0uvlrrd71vZw9kpd5PU7Xx0S9mIRL4W7BDOZlaqWLZgNZ4Xz3CWcyEGakMCP92CFjfeEMroKZL5pJcJym3aUMWTrFyoWfniHwjf3bi_WcMRP9JQSgWDPDW8nD_K_Cr2_A2R7tlVp5-WCgVUiijpruQvyVkgnz6C-yMRfSrGM2ixfea4RTpM9hP9VFF04Kmc_sPak55mNJcB_4E5FPDWaR6MfYw,&l10n=ru&cts=1585849312134%40%40events%3D%5B%7B%22event%22%3A%22click%22%2C%22id%22%3A%22a2qn36%22%2C%22cts%22%3A1585849312134%2C%22fast%22%3A%7B%22organic%22%3A1%7D%2C%22service%22%3A%22web%22%2C%22event-id%22%3A%22k8j1qgli8a%22%7D%5D&mc=1.9182958340544893&hdtime=12637 Вот тебе ссылочка на хабр ......